# Make a link count from 1 to 32 and reset back to 1?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I have something like this, but it just outputs the link with 1 at the end of it.

```
var pagelink = "http://www.roblox.com/catalog/browse.aspx?CatalogContext=1&Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=4&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=";
 var num = 1;
   var maxnum = 32;
   for(var i = num; i <= maxnum; i++){
  pagelink + num
}
```

So the output just returns:

```
http://www.roblox.com/catalog/browse.aspx?CatalogContext=1&Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=4&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=1
```

Comment: How do you do the output?

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for? A delimited list of links? An array?

Comment: @arcyqwerty I just want the link page number to go all the way to 32 and back

Comment: You want `pagelink + i`- but then you need to do something with that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jamiec I'm trying to scan a couple pages, and so I want to go to 32 and back to 1 after

Comment: What do you mean by "and back" ... back to 1? Your title says back to 32. So do you want `1, 2, 3, ..., 31, 32, 32, 32`?

Comment: Ok, how many times do you want it to go around? forever?

Comment: Surely if you've scanned pages from 1-32 then you're done? Why do you need to go back to 1?

Answer (score 0):

First - you need to do some js training. Check out eloquentjavascript.net and go to town.

Answer:

```
var pagelink = "http://www.roblox.com/catalog/browse.aspx?CatalogContext=1&Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=4&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=";
var num = 1;
var maxnum = 32;
// You need something to put the output in. Here's an array.
var links = [];
for(var i = num; i <= maxnum; i++) {
  links.push(pagelink + i);
}
return links;
```

Comment: Talking about js training, you're using the wrong var inside the loop. You clearly want `i` not `num`.

Comment: @Jamiec Ah, clearly, thanks for the catch. That's a mistake due to pasting the OP's code while attempting to help them, though, not a lack of training. Pretty unnecessarily sharp comment, friend. The OP does indeed need to train, there's no sign of any solid understanding of javascript.

Comment: Sorry, it was unnecessarily sharp on a read-back. It was meant to be ironic/sarcastic - yet again does not come over well on the internet. My Bad ;)

Comment: No problem. Agreed, text sucks for quick communication.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var pagelink = "http://www.roblox.com/catalog/browse.aspx?CatalogContext=1&Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=4&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=";
 var results = [];
 for(var i = 0; i <= **however many links you want**; i++){
   results.push(pagelink + (i % 32 + 1));
 }
 results // or if you want it delimited, results.join('\n') or whatever other delimiter you want
```

Your results will be stored in results and you can return it (if in a function) or use it for what you need

Comment: `i` not `num` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, but OP was having problems. Which means the idea is to *fix* their code. IMO you've made this worse. `however many links you want` in the code, yet still hardcoding the `32` below it. You could have used that part of the OP's code `maxnum=32`.

Comment: Well, OP seems to be asking for links numbered 1 to 32 for some unspecified number of links.  Constant could be used but appeared more like a variable being set immediately above it.  If it's supposed to be a constant, I'd uppercase it as well.

Comment: @Erick, glad I could help. Though for next time, consider making the question a little clearer since it seems like a lot of us had trouble figuring out what you wanted.  If your problem is solved, please hit the check mark next to the answer to mark the question as closed.